# mysql query to get count from a table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables like this:

```
Areas 
id      city_id         area
1       1               mayfield
2       2               cleveland

neighbourhood
id      neighbourhood   area_id
101     cayahoga        1
102     milan           1
103     downtown        2

Salons
id      neighbourhood_id
3       101
4       101
5       102
```

I am trying to get count of all Salons in all areas.

Like salons in areas (mayfield = 2, cleveland = 1)

Is it possible to do this in 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT areas.area,COUNT(Salons.id)
FROM areas
LEFT JOIN neighbourhood ON neighbourhood.area_id = areas.id
LEFT JOIN Salons ON Salons.neighbourhood_id = neighbourhood.id
GROUP BY areas.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select area,count(s.id) as salon_count FROM
Areas a
INNER JOIN neighbourhood n
ON a.id = n.area_id
INNER JOIN
Salons s on s.neigbourhood_id = n.id
GROUP BY area
```

Comment: not giving count like: mayfield 2, cleveland 1. It is just giving count = 3?

Comment: Not sure why that wouldn't work. I've just changed it to "count(s.id)"... Should work now...